# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, count, subquery, aggregate, identifier

I am trying to use below query to sort out the consumer list based on 
1)actual count and then 
2)subcount based on values as in Sla_state =1 and result =0 ..

**Query ..**

select  consumer as "Consumer", class_name as "Service", count(consumer) as "totalcount", avg(responsetime) as "AvgResponseTime (ms)", max(responsetime) as "Max ResponseTime (ms)" , sla_state as "sla", result  as "result_state" , count(1) as "subcount"
from
 DPOWER.business_transaction bt join DPOWER.mmfg_business_transaction mbt on 
(bt.business_trans_id = mbt.business_trans_id) join DPOWER.transaction_class tc on (bt.class_id = tc.class_id) and sla_state = 1 and result=0 
where
 (bt.starttime >= '20150701000000000000' and bt.endtime <= '20150801000000000000')  group by  consumer, sla_state, result, class_name order by  consumer

The above query worked ..but I am able to get only the subcount and not the total count of the consumers. Below is the three table structures.  Can anyone figure out how to get the total count .( i tried all possible way like count (*) etc but that didnt work out..also if I use aliases I get "multipart idenfier not bound" error.

Comment: `consumer in (select count(consumer) from DPOWER.business_transaction where sla_state = 1 and result=0)` doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Hanno can i use something like ...................................................................
 
consumer in (select count(1) as "Failed Txn Count" DPOWER.business_transaction where sla_state = 1 and result=0)

Comment: You should always alias all columns in your select. I have no idea which column came from which table which makes it hard to understand the query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ..but when I try to  include alias names ..i get "the multipart identifier for **col** is not bound" ...

Answer (score 0):

Could you mean this in your WHERE clause ??

```
where 
consumer in 
    (
        select 
            consumer
        from 
            DPOWER.business_transaction 
        where 
            sla_state = 1 
            and result=0
    ) 
and (bt.starttime >= '20150701000000000000' 
and bt.endtime <= '20150801000000000000')
```

Comment: yes .. i need a count of the " consumer " ..when  sla_state = 1 
            and result=0 in a separate column and also the actual count of consumer.

Comment: In that case you will have to join on `DPOWER.business_transaction` twice using an alias. Please include this information in your question, i.e. what the result should actually look like.

Comment: @HannoBinder ..Thanks ..Let me try it out

Comment: Any help would be grateful..above is my table structure

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, here's an idea:

```
select  
    bt1.consumer as "Consumer", 
    count(bt1.*) as totalcount,
    count(bt2.consumer) as subcount
from 
    DPOWER.business_transaction bt1
left outer join DPOWER.business_transaction bt2
  on bt1.consumer = bt2.consumer
  and bt2.sla_state = 1 
  and result=0
group by 
    bt1.consumer 
order by consumer
```

Comment: @hanno..I have edited the query above...as per your input . The column "consumer" is present only in table "DPOWER.mmfg_business_transaction" and that i have joined with DPOWER.business_transaction

Comment: In fact, the query should not be a subquery. Add the left outer join to your basic query!